# JavaFX vertical slider

Tags: slider, javafx

*I'm exploring `JavaFX` and I must say I'm little disappointed with the lack of learning material.* I'm rookie to `JavaFX` but I have some experience with `Swing`.
How can I place the slider vertically?
And one more question,I want the `Thumb` to be draggable only to the `Tick marks`,not in the intermediate space,how can I achieve that?

[image: slider]

Comment: -1: Lack of learning material? There's a whole lot of articles just [on the tutorial site](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) alone. There's also no substitute for actually looking through [the API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I place the slider vertically?

Use [setOrientation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#setOrientation%28javafx.geometry.Orientation%29)

```
slider.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
```

> I want the Thumb to be draggable only to the Tick marks,not in the intermediate space,how can I achieve that?

Use [setSnapToTicks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#setSnapToTicks%28boolean%29) after setting an appropriate tick unit, count and block increment.

```
slider.setMajorTickUnit(0.25f);
slider.setMinorTickCount(1);
slider.setBlockIncrement(0.125f);
slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
```

Sample app:

```
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VerticalSliderSample extends Application {
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    Slider slider = new Slider(0, 1, 0.5);
    slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
    slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
    slider.setMajorTickUnit(0.25f);
    slider.setMinorTickCount(1);
    slider.setBlockIncrement(0.125f);
    slider.setSnapToTicks(true);

    slider.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");
    layout.getChildren().setAll(slider);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

[image]

> I'm exploring JavaFX and I must say I'm little disappointed with the luck of learning material.

Email (constructive) feedback on Oracle developed JavaFX documentation to:

`jfx-docs-feedback_ww@oracle.com`

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 and with it JavaFX 8 and its corresponding [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) coming (at this time of post its still Java 7 GA with SceneBuilder 2.2), people should get more familiar using it. It is a powerful tool for people who don't know each special attribute from its hat off and want to practice the Inversion of Control principle the new JavaFX and its FXMLs offer us.

Here is an example out of one of my projects to show the most popular 
properties on each Node

[image]

Though I can sometimes understand you, for being frustrated especially if some new features come out, that some higher class examples what this Node can do and maybe find it easier, but as a programmer you need to learn to work with the corresponding API. It would be nice to have a part of each API documentation like in the PHP community where you can maintain it as a wiki.